# Angular 6: retrieve data from SelectionModel

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a component which has a mat-table with checkboxes using SelectionModel. Here is the code I have to retrieve the data selected.

```
fileSelect = new SelectionModel<FileInfo>(true, []);
```

This method is invoked in ngSubmit of the form.

```
sendFileInterrupt() {
 let selectedFileIds: string[];
    for (let item of this.fileSelect.selected) {
      console.log(item.fileId);
      selectedFileIds.push(item.fileId);
    }
```

The selected fileId is logged in console, but when trying to add it to the selectedFileIds array, I'm getting an error

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Do I have to instantiate or initialize the array before pushing data into it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initialize let selectedFileIds: string[] = [];

```
sendFileInterrupt() {
 let selectedFileIds: string[] = [];
    for (let item of this.fileSelect.selected) {
      console.log(item.fileId);
      selectedFileIds.push(item.fileId);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to iterate through `this.fileSelect.selected`, it is already an array of rows `rows[]`;